# How to find the maximum circle in a 2D array

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D `n*n` array with each element being either a `+` or a `x`, how can we find the maximum circle diameter made of only `+` chars.

For example:

```
xxxxx  
x++++
x+++x
x+++x
xxxxx
```

Would have a maximum diameter of 2 and the circle origin is the center.

The circle may not be centred in the 2D array in all cases.

Is there an easy algorithm to solve this? I'm not looking for code just an algorithm.
Thanks.

```
xxxxx
xx+xx
x+++x
xx+xx
xxxxx
```

Would be a circle of  diameter 2 to answer the question about edges.

Comment: Which is the definition of a circle in this problem? Just two perpendicular diameters of same length? I mean, in your example you have a 3x3 `+` square. How about if the edges are `x`. it would be considered a circle? Also, why the diameter of your example is 2 and not 3?

Comment: If the edges are x it is considered a circle

Comment: Ok! Then, there can only exist diameters with odd values, right?

Comment: You really need to define what you mean by circle. So what array elements belong to a circle of some radius? It is obviously not the set of elements that are intersected by the circle as your second example shows.

Comment: Yes only even diameters can exist. I.e the radius will be an integer.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to say **odd** .

Comment: An odd number of '+' chars but an even diameter if we take +++ to be a diameter of 2. Because a single '+' has no diameter does not form a circle

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean disks (rather than circles) in the taxicab-metric. But -- I would rather not guess and would prefer you to *explain*.

Comment: Yes disk may be a better term than circle

Comment: Still not clear what is meant by circle... if vertical and horizontal dimensions differ, is it still a circle?  What if it's shaped like a donut?  Or a duck?  Etc... (never mind - just saw the HackerRank comment)

Comment: [taxicab-metric circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry#Circles) are diamond-shaped. I doubt you mean that? Do you mean [circles like these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to tackle this problem, is to imagine the free cells (`+`) as sea, and the other cells (`x`) as land. The algorithm starts a water-wave at the coast line(s) that flows in all directions (until it hits another wave or land). The last piece of sea that gets covered by a wave is a centre of a circle with greatest radius.

This leads to this more formal algorithm:

1. Let `count` be the number of free cells (number of `+`).
2. If `count` is zero, exit without result.
3. Create an array `coast` with cell-coordinates of occupied cells (those with `x`)

   - Add also to the `coast` the virtual cells that lie just outside the grid, as they also represent "land".
4. Set `radius` to 1
5. Get the relative coordinates of a circle with this `radius` (as if centred on cell [0, 0]). So for radius 1 this would be:

   ```
   [ [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 0], [0, 1] ]
   ```
6. For each `centre` = cell referenced in `coast`:

   - Get the free cells on the circle with this `centre` and `radius`, and for each:

     - mark it as occupied, and decrease `count`
     - if `count` is zero, then we have a solution: this cell is the centre of the circle to draw, and it should have a radius of `radius-1`. Exit.
   - If none of the cells on this circle was free, remove `centre` from `coast` (to avoid unnecessary checks in the future)

7. Increase `radius` and repeat from step 5.

When the algorithm exits with a result (a centre and a radius), it is straightforward to overlay the given grid with the actual disk.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript (without using any of the newer syntax, so it should be straightforward to read), which you can run here:

```js
"use strict";
function circleCoordinates(radius) {
    var cells = [];
    var r2 = (radius+0.41)*(radius+0.41); // constant determines margin
    var i = 0;
    var j = radius;
    while (i <= j) {
        cells.push([ i,  j]);
        cells.push([ i, -j]);
        if (i < j) {
            cells.push([ j,  i]);
            cells.push([-j,  i]);
        }
        if (i) {
            cells.push([-i,  j]);
            cells.push([-i, -j]);
            if (i < j) {
                cells.push([j,  -i]);
                cells.push([-j, -i]);
            }
        }
        i++;
        if (i*i + j*j > r2) {
            j--; 
            // Decrementing i here is not standard, but needed to make 
            // sure we cover the surface added compared to a disk with 
            // a radius of one unit one less.            
            i--;
        }
    }
    return cells;
}

function solve(a) {
    var i, j, k, l, m, n, count, coast, circle, reduced, radius, b;

    function get(b, i, j) {
        if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= b.length || j >= b[i].length)
            return 1;
        return b[i][j];
    }

    // Copy input, count free cells, and collect the others in "coast"
    count = 0;
    coast = [];
    b = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            b[i].push(a[i][j]); // copy array element
            count += !b[i][j]; // count free cells
            if (b[i][j]) coast.push([i,j]); // push occupied cells
        }
    }
    if (!count) return; // no solution
    // To bound the area, add virtual border cells in 'coast':
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        coast.push([i, -1], [i, b[i].length]);
    }
    for (j = 0; j < b[0].length; j++) {
        coast.push([-1, j], [b.length, j]);
    }
    // Keep reducing free space by drawing circles from the coast
    // until one free cell is left over.
    radius = 0;
    while (count) {
        radius++;
        circle = circleCoordinates(radius);
        for (k = coast.length - 1; (k >= 0) && count; k--) {
            reduced = false;
            for (l = 0; (l < circle.length) && count; l++) {
                m = coast[k][0] + circle[l][0];
                n = coast[k][1] + circle[l][1];
                if (!get(b, m, n)) {
                    b[m][n] = radius+1;
                    count--;
                    reduced = true;
                }
            }
            // Save some time by removing the cell in the coast
            // list that had no reducing effect anymore:
            if (!reduced) coast.splice(k, 1);
        }
    }
    // Greatest circle has a radius that is one smaller:
    radius--;
    // Restore array to original
    for (i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Draw a disc centered at i, j
    circle = circleCoordinates(radius);
    for (l = 0; l < circle.length; l++) {
        for (k = m + circle[l][0]; k <= m - circle[l][0]; k++) {
            b[k][n+circle[l][1]] = 2;
        }
    }
    // Return the array with the marked disc
    return b;
}

// String handling

function cleanText(txt) {
    return txt.trim().replace(/[ \r\t]/g, '').replace(/[^x\n]/g, '+');
}

function textToArray(txt) {
    var lines, a, i, j;
    // Clean text and split into lines
    lines = cleanText(txt).split('\n');
    // convert to 2D array of 0 or 1:
    a = [];
    for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        a[i] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < lines[i].length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = +(lines[i][j] !== '+'); // '+' => 0, 'x' => 1
        }
    }
    return a;
}

function arrayToText(a) {
    // Convert 2D array back to text. 2-values will be translated to '#'
    var lines, i, j;
    lines = [];
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        lines[i] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            lines[i][j] = '+x#'[a[i][j]]; // mark disc with '#'
        }
        lines[i] = lines[i].join('');
    }
    return lines.join('\n');
}

// I/O handling for snippet:

var inp = document.querySelector('textarea');
var solveBtn = document.querySelector('#solve');
var clearBtn = document.querySelector('#clear');

solveBtn.onclick = function() {
    // Convert input to 2D array of 0 and 1 values:
    var a = textToArray(inp.value);
    // Draw greatest disk by replacing 0-values with 2-values:
    a = solve(a);
    // Convert 2D array back to text. 2-values will be translated to '#'
    inp.value = arrayToText(a);
};

clearBtn.onclick = function() {
    inp.value = cleanText(inp.value);
};
```

```html
<button id="solve">Show Greatest Disc</button>
<button id="clear">Remove Disc</button><br>
<textarea rows=10>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx++++++x++++++
+++x+++++++x+++++x
++++x+++++++++++x+
++++x+++++x++++x++
+++x+++++++x+++x+x
x+++++xx+++++x++++
xx+++++x+++++x+++x
++++++xxxx++xxxx++
xxx++xxxxxxxxxxxx+
++xxxxxxxxx+xxxxxx</textarea>
<pre></pre>
```